# SQL LEFT and patindex

Tags: sql, sql-server, patindex

I am trying to write a select query that takes off the leading zeros and takes of all characters that are not numeric.  I figured out how to do one or the other just not both at the same time.

So far I have:

```
SELECT 
    Substring(rt_VehicleName, patindex('%[^0]%', rt_VehicleName), +4),
    [rt_Odometer],
    [rt_CumHours],
    [Date],
    [Emco] 

FROM 
    [GPS_Data].[dbo].[Engine_Hours]
```

and the results are 28 S. I want to get rid of the S

Comment: Great!  You seem to be learning SQL.  If you have a question, follow the guidelines on the site for asking a question.

Comment: What have you got for your LEFT() and PATINDEX() queries?  It'd be easier to combine them if you edit your question and show what you've already got.

Comment: SELECT Substring(rt_VehicleName, patindex('%[^0]%',rt_VehicleName),+4)
      ,[rt_Odometer]
      ,[rt_CumHours]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Emco]
  FROM [GPS_Data].[dbo].[Engine_Hours]                                                    The results are 28 S.  I want to get rid of the S

Answer (score 0):

This query seems overcomplicated but it works in my data.

```
select top 10 SUBSTRING(LEFT(SUBSTRING([Your Column Here], PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', [Your Column Here]), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING([Your Column Here], PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', [Your Column Here]), 8000) + 'X') -1), PATINDEX('%[^0]%', [Your Column Here]+'.'), LEN([Your Column Here])) as 'No 0s or Letters', * from [Your Table Here]
```

[image]